# calling predict on the loaded model in keras returns the probaility value of each action not the prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am writing an RL program with keras.
The program builds a NN model and then uses that model to predict the situation.
```def _build_model(self):

````
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(24,input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation ='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))

    return model```
````

I use action = model.predict(state) in each episode.
In the end I use keras.save(name) to save the model before exiting the program.
As I mentioned, I use model.predict() in each episode of the game to select an action and it returns an action out of 8 actions[0 to 7]

But if I write a piece of code and use keras.models.load_model(name) and then call
action = model.predict(state), it returns an array of 8 elements which are probability of each action, not the selected action that  expect.

I need to add that if I don't want to save the model to deploy and use it later, it is working fine. All the results and outputs sound logical but if I decide to save it for later to just put it in the new environment and it takes action, I cannot as I explained above.
How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How do you know that the output of this model are probabilities, and not just numbers? This model is not configured to output a probability distribution. Please add some evidence.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's how `predict()` works actually, It returns probabilities. It's your job to map those probabilities to your classes (labels). Knowing that the predictions are mapped to your input classes (In order), you could find out the index of maximum probability.

Simple example:

```
predictions = [0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
np.argmax(x) # Returns 1
```

**NOTE: This is in case you outputs are probabilities! Question's a bit misleading.**

Comment: No, this is completely wrong, predict() returns the output of the model, which for some models is probabilities, this model does not return probabilities (there is no softmax at the output).

Comment: True, no Softmax for the last layer. Also note it's stated in the question: "it returns an array of 8 elements which are probability of each action, not the selected action that expect.". As you said, there aren't enough evidence so I answered by the statement he made, not the code. No need for a downvote (:

Comment: The problem is that other people will read your answer and be mislead by it, I do not think the OP is interpreting the model output correctly, and this misinterpretation will spread. And yes, downvotes are for this exact reason, wrong answers.